# Behavior of a sum

Tags: asymptotics, constraints

Let $n$ a positive value and let us consider any increasing function $f(x)$.

What is the asymptotic behavior of the lowest $k$ (using for instance $O$) which fulfil the following constraint

$$\sum_{i=1}^k f(i) \geq n$$

?

Thank you.

Comment: Assuming $f(1)>0$, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^kf(i)>\sum_{i=1}^kf(1)=kf(1)\ge n\implies k>\frac n{f(1)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your result @SimplyBeautifulArt . Can we not improve this bound, asymptotically? I am looking for the behavior of the lowest $k$ satisfying the inequation. Besides, I am especially interested by an upper asymptotic bound.

Comment: I think we'll need more information then.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank you for your remark. So, we cannot generalize? For instance, can we say that $k_{min}=O(\frac{n}{f(n)})$?

Comment: No, we can't.  If $f(n)\gg n$, then this is saying that as $n\to\infty$, $k\to0$, which is clearly false.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Can we say that $\sum_{i=1}^k f(i) \sim k f(k)$? Can we use that to solve the problem? Thanks again.

Comment: As I said, no, we can't say that.  Consider $f(n)=n$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt If $f(n)=n$ then $\sum_{i=1}^k i = k(1+k)/2 \sim k^2$. We can write it. Do you mean that we can't use this equivalence to solve the inequation?

Comment: Pretty sure $k(k+1)/2\sim k^2/2\not\sim k^2$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sorry $\sum_{i=1}^k i = k(1+k)/2 \sim k^2/2$. Can we use it? I'm looking for a methodology.

Comment: No, we can't use it... We need a **lower bound** for this to work, and $kf(k)$ is the maximum **upper bound**.